# Android Studio error - Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@231a2345

Tags: android-studio

Keep getting - Can not extract resource from com.android.aaptcompiler.ParsedResource@231a2345.

Here's a link to my code there is the Main Activity java and the Activity Main xml files

https://long-salsa-95c.notion.site/8caff50a45aa4807b6e1531106dc30ad?v=1ef0ec33f0544b1793f63bb19b8fdbf1

Comment: same issue with a library import. . .
I add the library and it gives me error, without the import works fine

Comment: did you find any solution for the resource merging error?

Comment: Same error, I just modified the string xml resource file

Answer (score 4):

Check your resource string files, maybe some of them has the ' without the backslah \'

Answer (score 4):

Replace the **'** with **\'** in String files, or make sure you add **#** before the color code like **#001B3C**

Answer (score 0):

You need to create correct resource type.
For example, if you open raw resource type then put the file there in res/raw and access as below. In below, we have file named project_json.json (can be any file extension).

```
val inputStream: InputStream = resources.openRawResource(R.raw.product_json)
```

Plus remove ' with '

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I put another style inside one
[image: inner style in themes]